# iterating over a list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does when I run :

```
a = ['a','n','g']
b = [range(0,4)]

print [(x,y) for x in a for y in b]
```

returns :

```
[('a', [0, 1, 2, 3]), ('n', [0, 1, 2, 3]), ('g', [0, 1, 2, 3])]
```

but when I run this piece of code:

```
a = ['a','n','g']
b = [0,1,2,3,4]

print [(x,y) for x in a for y in b]
```

It returns:

```
[('a', 0), ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('a', 4), ('n', 0), ('n', 1), ('n', 2), ('n', 3), ('n', 4), ('g', 0), ('g', 1), ('g', 2), ('g', 3), ('g', 4)]
```

So as you may have noticed, if I use the range function, I get a wrong output but If I manually key in *['a','n','g']* I get the desired output

```
b = [range(0,4)]
and
b = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Both are obviously the same right? therefore why do there results vary *(if they are the same)* ?

I'm basically trying to build a program which has **A** in a range of 999 reversed and **B** with a range of 999 and believe me hard coding those 1000 digits is not efficient and I might probably be considered insane

Comment: Obviously no, thery are not the same, range(0,4) is [0,1,2,3]

Comment: why not look at `b` after you set `b = [range(0,4)]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[range(0,4)]` is the same as `[[0,1,2,3]]`, so it is very much not the same as `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

I think you just want `range(0,5)` (note that there are no square brackets around this, and to include `4` in the result you need to have `5` for the `stop` argument of `range()`).

And for your specific problem: "I'm basically trying to build a program which has `A` in a range of 999 reversed and `B` with a range of 999":

```
A = range(999, -1, -1)
B = range(1000)
```

This assumes that you want ranges like `[999, 998, ..., 1, 0]` and `[0, 1, ..., 998, 999]`.

Comment: Thanks, this might have sounded a stupid question to you but for me its something quite big

Answer (score 4):

> Both are obviously the same right?

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [range(0,4)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

The two are not the same; you probably meant `b = range(0,4)` without the extra set of brackets.

Answer (score 3):

No, these two are not the same. You can think of

```
[range(0, 4)]
```

as this

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Note it is a list of lists.

So when you are doing a list comprehension over this list, it will simply iterate over the single element `[0, 1, 2, 3]` over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously no, thery are not the same, range(0,4) is [0,1,2,3]

Note that is different than: [range(0,4)] and [[0,1,2,3] ]

Check any python source.

[Link](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html)